How to only allow certain LAN IPs of a Wireguard spoke to be accessible by other spokes?
In my setup, there are HostA.2 and HostB spokes connected to Wireguard hub Host C. There are services in LAN A, the local subnet of HostA.2, HostA.3 and so on:
wg1:                           172.16.0.1    172.16.0.2   172.16.0.1
LAN A:  10.0.0.4   10.0.0.3    10.0.0.2
        HostA.4 -- HostA.3  -- HostA.2  ---> HostC   <--- HostB

How do I limit HostA.2 via PostUp iptables rules so that only certain LAN IPs, e.g. 10.0.0.3, will be accessible by spokes like HostB?

What packets do you actually have? The easiest way to figure out such things is to run a packet capture (on both interfaces) and see the real source/destination for yourself, without needing to guess and assume.

In case someone wonders why @u1686_grawity gave me this suggestion, I clarified my objective, and updated the question accordingly. Therefore this comment might seem out of place.

After trying different combination of rules, the following worked:
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i %i -j DROP
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i %i -d 10.0.0.3 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens18 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i ens18 -o %i -j ACCEPT

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j DROP
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -d 10.0.0.3 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens18 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i ens18 -o %i -j ACCEPT

The solution here first accepts the packets if they are destined for a allowed IP in the LAN A, then any other packets are dropped. After they are accepted, the nat rule masquerades it, send it through ens18, and the last rules lets the response return back into the Wireguard subnet.
This way, security does not have to rely on the nat masquerading rules, nor relying on the return rule. Bot of which would mean the packet has already reached undesirable hosts on LAN A.
In my original question, I posted some config lines, but due to me taking wg1 up and down constantly, some rules were left over, and therefore they were not representative. Therefore the question was revamped.
